# how to install bittorrent sync on amazon ec2 using nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, bittorrent

I have been trying to install and configure bittorrent sync on ec2 instance running ubuntu 14.04 and nginx. I have followed this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bittorrent-sync-to-synchronize-directories-in-ubuntu-14-04 but when I put listen server_domain_or_IP:8888 ssl; in the server block, it will give error when restarting nginx.

So then I followed instruction on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191509/nginx-error-99-cannot-assign-requested-address answered by kirpit and then that error gone. But when I try to load the interface at https://server_domain_or_IP:8888 it won't load giving error as follows:

> Can't load the page because the server where this page is located
>   isn't responding.

I have opened port 8888 in security group but no luck.

I have spent few hours but no success. But I was able to do this on a digitalocean droplet on same ubuntu 14.04, so not sure why it doesn't work on ec2. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I can tell you it does work, as I had it working at one point. I can't tell you any more because I turned it off and used Dropbox sync instead, but I wanted to let you know that yes it can work.

Comment: on that ec2 I have a website published so another server block is there with port 80, can that cause this problem?

Comment: I've just quickly created a new ec2 instance and fresh installed bittorrent with only one server block but same problem. Same thing worked with digitalocean but not working with ec2, very strange, no idea what could go wrong..

Comment: Are your security groups, internet gateway, and routing table set up correctly?

Comment: Not sure how and if I need to do anything on gateway and routing, but you can check this http://54.86.50.89 shows nginx default page, which means IP is working, but when I put https://54.86.50.89:8888 it won't work. But same thing work on digitalocean here https://162.243.207.214:8888

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by simply adding the following lines of code inside my existing server block:

```
location /gui {
    rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
}
```

This was inside ssl 443 server block, but I think it will also work on non-ssl block. Then I could access the application by visiting https://www.example.com/gui/

That way I solved the problem, however I finally could not use bittorrent sync because it does not sync content from a soft linked directory, instead it treats soft links as soft links and copy over. I contacted their support and they said that is not supported, which is also mentioned here http://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/205504529-Soft-links-hard-links-and-symbolic-links

I hope anyone facing similar problem as mine be benefited from it.